# How to keep my data on Google Cloud and give different permission to various users

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am new to GCP.  I need technical help to use the GCP as data storage and give different permissions to different users of my organization.

Answer (score 0):

In order to give different permissions to different users of your organization I recommend you to take a look at the [GCP documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam) about Identity and Access Management.

IAM allows you to control who has access to the resources in your Google Cloud project. Resources include Cloud Storage buckets and objects stored within buckets, as well as other Google Cloud entities such as Compute Engine instances.

I suggest reviewing the following guides that describe how to control access to buckets and objects using Identity and Access Management (IAM) permissions. IAM allows you to control who has access to your buckets and objects.

Guides:

- [Using IAM with buckets](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/using-iam-permissions#bucket-iam)
- [Viewing the IAM policy for a bucket](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/using-iam-permissions#bucket-view)
- [Using IAM Conditions on buckets](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/using-iam-permissions#conditions-iam)
- [Using IAM with projects](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/using-iam-permissions#project-iam)

Additionally you can check more information about IAM roles for Cloud Storage in this [link](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles) where you will find a table that  describes Identity and Access Management (IAM) roles that are associated with Cloud Storage and lists the permissions that are contained in each role.